# How can I programmatically erase PDF margins using Kofax Power Advanced and VBA/VB?

Tags: vba, vb.net, pdf, crop, kofax

I have an issue with cropping several PDFs of various sizes.
In Kofax there's an option called "Remove White Margins". How can I achieve the same thing using VB/VBA?

EDIT : Here's a sample PDF. [SAMPLE FILE](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d57ac63f7df4f090a7326b16bab61cf420240325122818/aa0b80)

Cropping margins in Kofax:

[image: Remove white margin]

Example of the PDFs I'm cropping:

[image: PDF]

Comment: @KJ Thx for your answer, you'll find a sample in the original post.